# Have there been any recent lunar rovers?

Tags: the-moon, rovers

It seems that most rover-related attention recently has been on Mars, with Curiosity recently getting there.

However, it seems there are also benefits to exploring places a little closer to home, such as the moon.

Have there been any unmanned surface missions to the moon in the past decade? Have there been *any*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in the last decade, no. The Russian [Luna 24](http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/profile.cfm?Print=0&Sort=Nation&MCode=Luna_24&Nation=USSR&Display=ReadMore&FIELDNAMES=) was the last unmanned lunar rover, and it was deployed in 1976.

However, there are several *planned* lunar rovers, such as the Chinese [Chang'e 3](http://www.americaspace.com/?p=35272) rover. It is scheduled for launch in **December 2013** - fairly soon!

> [image]
>
> After landing, a solar-powered rover will roll off the lander and commence its mission, which is expected to last for at least three months, although presumably that will include a lot of down-time while the two-week-long lunar nights prevail.
>
> The Chang’e 3 lander itself will continue to operate as a stationary science platform. It will be powered by a radioisotope thermoelectric generator and hence will be largely unaffected by the presence or absence of direct sunlight. The lander will operate a number of science instruments, including an optical telescope and a “soil probe” to conduct analyses of lunar regolith.
>
> The Chang’e 3 rover will have a mass of 120 kilograms, including a 20 kg science payload.

Comment: Luna 24 was not a rover, but a stationary lander. There were 2 unmanned moon rovers in that era: Lunokhod 1 and 2.

Answer (score 9):

### Update 2019:

- The Chinese [Chang'e 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_3) mission landed the [Yutu rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yutu_(rover)) (meaning "jade rabbit") in December 2013.  The rover was mobile for 42 days and communicated for 973 days.  Its ground-penetrating radar discovered 9 rock layers, and it photographed a terran eclipse of the Sun.
- [Chang'e 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4) landed the Yutu 2 rover on the far side of the moon in January 2019.  It is still operational and the only operational rover on the moon.
- India is scheduled to launch [Chandrayaan-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrayaan-2) on July 14.  It will land near Chang'e 4 and carry the Pragyaan rover.
- Other scheduled rovers include an amateur German group (ALQ, 2020), a Mexican micro-rover (Peregrine, 2020), a small Chilean rover (Unity, 2020), a Carnegie-Mellon University rover (CubeRover, 2021), a JAXA rover (SLIM, 2021), and a private Japanese rover (ispace, 2021).